# How do I view the "System" level Audit log events via the Bitbucket Server UI?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I can see the Repository level Audit log in the Repository Settings, and I can see the Project level Audit log in the Project Settings.

What about the "System" level audit log which contains Server, User Management, Permission events, etc., per https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/audit-events-in-bitbucket-server-776640423.html?

I am on version 5.1, and I have "System Admin" permission, but I do not have access to the logs on the server (i.e. /log/audit).  Also, I exported the support zip via "Support Tools" with all application logs enabled, and it does not appear to contain the audit logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't see the "System" level audit logs via Bitbucket server UI. You only can see these logs looking at the files located at BITBUCKET_HOME/log directory at the Bitbucket server machine.

Comment: If anyone sees this answer and doesn't like it (like myself), then vote for this issue here https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-10227

Comment: Nice idea @successhawk.